# Legal SMS or not

Tags: sms

I ordred an item from a website but everytime they send different item when i call them they send me an sms and ask if my my bank account is linked to my UPI and ask me to forward that sms to a particular number that sms is "UBREG quSvehhySFNw1nHM2sEilU+C/GKZNT7cX3NrInL9O1DS7KNBZV5EqlcsWl6Nj5899e4HyovXbmdMoKr+thYNpA==".

Please can anyone help me out is this a legal sms or they are trying to access to my phone and then gain access on my bank account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is not about programming related matter

Comment: That looks like mobile verification sms used by banking apps. Don't send it to anyone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

By this, they will gain VPN access to your mobile and will withdraw all the money. Please don't forward this SMS.